# Oracle BI Pivot Table Results

Tags: oracle

I am having difficulty displaying information in a pivot table in Oracle BI.  This is my first post for Oracle so be gentle with the correction please.  My tables and columns are;

Rows

```
TRIP BEGIN DATE, Date
TRIP, Day of week
TRIP, Hour
```

Columns

```
TRIP, Trip Origin ID
```

Measures

```
TRIP, Routes
```

My pivot gives me what I am looking for on a daily basis, however I am wanting to get an average by day of week.  So the out put of the pivot is roughly,

```
Date       Day of Week        Hour        1234
6/2/2013   1                  15          15
6/9/2013   1                  15          16
6/16/2013  1                  15          14
```

I am trying to display the average op these three values.  When I remove Date from teh Pivot table and change the TRIP, Routes value to average here is what I get...

```
Day of Week      Hour      1234
1                15        45
```

I want to display

```
Day of Week      Hour      1234
1                15        15
```

Any thoughts on how to properly display an average of teh 1234 column in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was relatively simple.  With all fields set in their respective Rows columns and Measures, I selected the more options for my measure Trip.  For Show Data As I selected Values, for Aggregation Rule I selected Average.  This returned the information I was looking for.